# Firebase Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value but the function works

Tags: firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

Hi I have a function that works but gives me an error of Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value in the middle. I do not understand why. The functions works though.
Please help

Thanks in advance..

[image]

here is the function

```
'use-strict'

 const functions = require("firebase-functions");
 const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 const firebase = admin.initializeApp();

 exports.deleteFriendChatMessagesImageFolder = 
 functions.database.ref('/messagesFriends/{userId}/{friendId}')
            .onDelete((snap, context) => {

 const userId = context.params.userId;
 const friendId = context.params.friendId;

 const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket();

 console.log(userId + ' ' + friendId + " found")

 return bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: `messages_image_from_friends/`+userId+`/`+friendId
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
   console.log(`messages_image_from_friends/`+userId+`/`+friendId + ` remove error`);
            } else {
   console.log(`messages_image_from_friends/`+userId+`/`+friendId + ` removed`);
                }
                  });

 });
```

Where should i put the promise to make the error go away. Again the function works! So i am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a callback to deleteFiles, it does not return anything ([source](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/358be8d9b0424d8c0bc24f9d85fb7330b0d4f975/src/bucket.ts#L1636)).
This is a common pattern with JS APIs: either use a callback or return a promise.
Here is how you could modify your code to use promises:

```
 return bucket.deleteFiles({
        prefix: `messages_image_from_friends/`+userId+`/`+friendId
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`messages_image_from_friends/`+userId+`/`+friendId + ` removed`)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`messages_image_from_friends/`+userId+`/`+friendId + ` remove error`)
    });
```

A good place to learn about promises is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).